# What is the char represented by keycode (15) c#?

Tags: c#, sql, string, keycode

I have a string which is pulled from a SQL database using EF, through a view.
string sample is "mystring" with length of 8.
When I compare this string to "mystring" I am getting "false".

I've converted the string to (byte) array:

```
("mystring").Select(m=>(byte)m).ToArray();
```

I see I have an extra char with keycode "15" at the end of the array.

I've looked anywhere what is the keycode '15' and I didn't see it in the keycode tables.

My questions are:

1. What is the char represented by "15" when converted to byte?
2. Why is it added to the string? (it is a string that my users can change with admin screen)

Added: it doesn't happen every time, only with (for now) one string.

Edit: I copy paste part of that string to Immediate window, to check for Length and I get Length = 2

This is the string:

```
"a‏".Length 
2
```

The GetBytes in UF8 of this string is:

```
{byte[4]}
[0]: 97
[1]: 226
[2]: 128
[3]: 143
```

The int value of the 2nd char (which does not exist in my eyes) is:

```
var intvalue = (int)test[1];
8207
```

Update: Now when I do inspect element on that "a" string i copy pasted before I see "a&rlm" --> what is it and how I get rid of it?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.asciitable.com. It is `shift in` (whatever that means) or `negative acknowledge`, depending if your 15 is decimal or hex.

Comment: It is decimal, I think it is that "shift in" but I don't know what it means (and why it is stored in sql, or who addes it on the 'road')

Comment: What kind of SQL gets the data out? And how do you save the value in in the first place? Is the column `varchar` or `nvarchar`? Are you doing the transformation on the SQL server or in the C# application? Unless your users are using teletype, it's pretty unlikely this is a valid submission - it might very well be a malicious attempt by your users, or some application interacting with the user's input (it's usually a good idea to `Trim` all user-input strings, to get them rid of non-visible characters).

Comment: Octal 15 is carriage return, which is more likely that either of those two to be found in a string.  Even MORE likely is that it's the U+010F `ď` unicode character, which would result in a value of `15`(`0F` in hex)  when cast to `byte` (since the "upper" byte is lost in the cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the string you have in your question in the HTML source it is written as `a&rlm;`. A quick google shows that rlm is the left to right mark which is unicode U+200F (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).

Combine this with other people's observation that casting to byte leaves only the final byte explains why you are getting 0F = 15 as your byte number.

Where this is coming from is something for you to investigate but I would imagine it comes from the original user input (ie the user is inputting text right to left).

Comment: ok thanks, now how do I get rid of it?? Replace ("&rlm","") doesn't work

Comment: `@rlm;` is the HTML entity for it. you just need to create a char by any of the normal methods with the correct value and use that in your replace. eg `Replace("\u200f", "");`

Answer (score 4):

A [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) in .NET is **not** a `byte`. Your conversion from `string` to `byte` array is flawed.

You need to use [GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the bytes in an encoding of your choice.

Comment: Thanks you are right that I need to use the GetBytes, but this array is not flawed, it shows the keycodes pressed, rather than the Unicode representation of that char. My problem is that this '15' keycode does not exist on the string, it doesn't matter to me if its unicode or not

Comment: @Ziv You have cast away half the bytes that your string consists of. As it's only ASCII chars, that's probably eight bytes of zero, but still... you threw away data. That's what I meant with "flawed".

Comment: @ZivWeissman Umm, .NET `string`s have nothing to do with keycodes. That's an entirely separate system. Why aren't you using `varbinary` if you care about keycodes, rather than strings?

Comment: Added the getbytes of that string (the end of it)

Answer (score 3):

Your character is likely not the ASCII character with a code `15`, but is the *Unicode* character with a value of `XX0F`.  When you cast a unicode character to `byte`, you lose the "upper" byte since unicode characters are two bytes.

I don't know how that applies to your `"mystring"` comparison, but I suspect you're looking for something that ends with one character and getting something that ends with another.  I'm not an expert in cultures, so perhaps a culture-sensitive search is appropriate?

Note that *any* unicode character ending in `0F` would result in a vlaue of `15`.  Here are the first 15:

```
010f ď 
020f ȏ 
030f ̏ 
040f Џ 
050f ԏ 
060f ؏ 
070f ܏ 
080f ࠏ 
090f ए 
0a0f ਏ 
0b0f ଏ 
0c0f ఏ 
0d0f ഏ 
0e0f ฏ 
0f0f ༏
```

Comment: I've voted for your effort, but the problem is that there is no additional (seen) char - the string is "mystring" when I look in debug, or immediate, or xml view, or whatever I tried. There is no additional char that I see on the screen. I can't do it now, but I will update when I can use the "GetBytes" method

Comment: Have you looked at the hex values to make sure they are the same (before converting it to `byte`?  Have you tried casting to `int` instead of `byte` and see if you get the same results?

Comment: I will try now - this is the string: "a‏"